# Why won't gloss show on flat areas after bake? [ Image added]

Tags: texturing

So, in rendered view, it shows the gloss on the front part of the cell phone and everywhere else as depicted, but after it's baked there's no gloss to show on the front or back, only on the sides. I'm using Cycles Render.[image]

Comment: You can't bake physical lighting from camera view in cycles, but may be possible with Blender Internal renderer depends on the material settings.

Comment: Your roughness looks high. Alternatively, you can upload a .blend file to [Blend Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com).